# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7

Tags: validation, dynamic, frameworks, store

I have a Swift project that uses a ObjC dynamic framework, the framework had to be linked with and embedded into my project. The project runs OK in devices, when submitted to App Store, the error occurred during validation:
`Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21`

Below are the validation logs:

```
2015-10-12 02:32:33 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: MusicFans, task: Validate
2015-10-12 02:32:33 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreValidation: 0x7f851c1d96c0>
2015-10-12 02:32:34 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f851b42db10:'/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2015-10-12 02:32:34 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f8529a08050:'/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/wavpack.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/wavpack.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/wavpack.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2015-10-12 02:32:34 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7f850da13de0:'/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/FLAC.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/FLAC.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/panzhansheng/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-10-11/MusicFans 11-10-15 上午8.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MusicFans.app/FLAC.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2015-10-12 02:33:07 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

If I remove the dynamic framework from the project’s Embedded frameworks section, then it can pass the validation, but crashes when run in devices due to the missing image of my dynamic framework, any idea?
BTW, dynamic framework has bitcode disabled, so my project also disables bitcode, and is not codesigned.

Comment: Did you use CocoaPods?

Comment: I got the Mach-O error when using XCode 12.4, and the Facebook iOS SDK (via Swift Package Manager). After hours of tearing my hair, I simply had to select Facebook iOS SDK 9.3 instead of the latest version. Before figuring this out I've fiddled with setting generating bitcode=no, arm64-compilation options, build environment variables, etc, so don't go down that rabbit hole. The Mach-O error displayed when building and attempting upload to AppStore, and it first seemed to have something to do with my iOS Widget Extension (appex a.k.a. plugin) which wasn't the case.

Answer (score 82):

Check two things for every framework:

1. The Mach-O type of the framework (in Build Settings of the framework target)

[image: Mach-O]

2. Whether you copy the framework by putting it in Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks (or Copy Bundle Resources as mentioned by a. brooks hollar)

[image: Embed frameworks]

If the Mach-O type of the framework is "static library", it should *not* be put in embed frameworks; if the Mach-O type is "dynamic library", it *should* be put in embed frameworks.

In my case it was SocketRocket I added manually which has both a static library target and a dynamic library target with the same framework name. After deleting the static library target and only embed the dynamic library framework, the problem disappears.

---

*Note*:

If you don't have access to the source project, you can manually check if it's a dynamic or static framework using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32591983/308315

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem in my case. I had Firebase in the Embedded Frameworks.

Comment: Very good explanation of dynamic and static libraries.  2 hours already searching

Comment: Should we assume that "Embeded Frameworks" is now equal to the section "Embedded Binaries"?

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. @pzs7602 accept it? :)

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie I'm not sure. But it seems that all embed frameworks also appear in embedded binaries.

Comment: What should the Mach-O type be for an iOS app, "Executable"?

Comment: @PetrusTheron Yes

Answer (score 25):

I don't know why but somehow pods appeared to become an **embedded binary**. So I had to remove it, pod install once more, and the issue disappeared.

[image]

On Xcode 11 you need to change it to `Do Not Embed` in the Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

Comment: Thanks is not enough to express my gratitude.

Answer (score 23):

Double check Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources for a framework or other binary that shoundn't be there.

In my case, it was a 3rd party library (Parse) that I had added.

Comment: In my case it was a file which was copied to the project. I removed this and the error disappeared. I then re-added the file and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: If you click on the "Show log" button, and then look at the "verbose" logfile, you may see the name of the offending framework. At least it was there for me.

Comment: +1 for this answer, basically in { App Target } -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources I deleted anything related to CocoaPods in there - made this issue go away

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I have a framework manually dragged into my project, and it is listed in `General`->`Embedded Binaries`, which cause error `Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21`. After i moved it from `Embedded Binaries` to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, problem solved.

Answer (score 16):

If you (potentially but not necessarily) used FirebaseSDK (especially Analytics) and get Mach-O error while running, archiving and uploading, try this:

Add this as a build **post-actions script**.

```sh
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework"
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework"
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework"
```

if you added **widgets** and/or other plugin extensions add these lines as well:

```sh
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/PlugIns/FirebaseAnalytics.framework"
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/PlugIns/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework"
rm -rf "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/PlugIns/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework"
```

[image]

Brief explanation:
The below quote is from the relevant discussion under https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472 explains the reason behind this problem.

> ... so right now the firebase framework artifacts are being copied into
> the /Frameworks folder of the ipa and are embedded. The frameworks
> themselves are static frameworks.... If you delete them from the
> xcarchive manually, everything works as expected.

Basically many of the answers here point to the right direction, but the problem remains because the solution is to remove the unwanted artifacts every single time. Currently (Jan 2021) AFAIK there is no other way to solve it.

Comment: This is what worked for me (even if you're not using firebase). Actually this answer did not help me as it is, I found the solution in this comment precisely: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472#issuecomment-740186615

Comment: This also worked for me, I was using Firebase with SPM and a Widget, Thanks you!

Comment: Make sure to select your app from `Provide build settings from [your_app_target]` in the select box.

Comment: Same as @Luca : using Firebase with SPM (without Widgets) and this also worked for me when archiving and uploading to AppSore. Thank you !

Answer (score 14):

Scheme->Edit Scheme->Archive->Post Action->Click '+' -> New Run Script Action->
paste below code

```
LOGFILE="${ARCHIVE_PATH}/static-frameworks.log"
echo "Removing static frameworks from ${WRAPPER_NAME} archive" > $LOGFILE
find "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/Applications/${WRAPPER_NAME}" -name '*.framework' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fm; do
    name=$(basename "${fm}" .framework)
    target="${fm}/${name}"
    echo "Checking: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    if file "${target}" | grep -q "current ar archive"; then
        rm -rf "${fm}"
        echo "Removed static framework: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    fi
done
```

[image]

Comment: done. worked for me. you saved my day man!

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked with Firebase using SPM !

Answer (score 10):

I had a same issue. I did a couple of things and my issue went away. I believe My issue was related to Cocoapods version but you can try couple of things here.

First clean DerivedData by:

> 1.Turn off Xcode
>
> 2.Go to ./Users/YourFile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
>
> 3.Delete everything from this folder
>
> 4.Run Xcode
>
> 5.Build&Clean

Second for some reason, with latest cocoa pods version 0.39, I was getting following warning when I ran `pod install`

> [!] The `MY_TARTGET` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

I've downgraded cocoapods by removing all installed cocoapods:

> sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

then install older version:

> sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.38.1

This removed the warning and I was able to remove the error, "unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"

Comment: I did this - also did pod install - problem went away. Thanks this was quite brilliant.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped.

Comment: I tried the steps you outlined progressively and I got over the finish line when I uninstalled/downgraded cocoapods. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

For me, I had Fabric binaries in my Carthage `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks` run script.

After removing those, it fixed the issue.

I'm using Xcode `Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)`

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I'm using Xcode `Version 10.3 (10G8)`. However I'm wondering if we still need to copy over `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework`.

Comment: I can't answer that question. But there is a run script that fabric requires you to add to your build scripts invoking `${PROJECT_DIR}/Carthage/Build/iOS/Fabric.framework/run`. My guess is that this is performing whatever needs to be done.

Answer (score 8):

In XCode 11, click on the project file, select your target, then on General tab expand Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content, change Embed & Sign to Do Not Embed.

Comment: Works under Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500). I have read the logs and changed this for all my third party frameworks. Some "libSwift_XXX" frameworks also were repaired since they did not appear anymore after this change.

Comment: This results in a runtime error in my case `dyld: Library not loaded`

Comment: all my lib are "Do not embed" and still the same error.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**: This looks to be fixed in Xcode 8 Beta 3.

I'm currently experiencing this issue with Xcode 8 Beta 2 and Swift 3 with pure-swift Pods (which seems to be causing the issue).

Adding the following to my Podfile has fixed the problem.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Credit goes to [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5598#issuecomment-230662508) by YuAo on GitHub.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this **Apple** documentation 
[Embedding Frameworks in An App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html) go to the section **Embedded Static Libraries** they explain this error like this:

> This is caused by placing a static library in a bundle structure that looks like a framework; this packaging is sometimes referred to by third party framework developers as a static framework. Since the binary in these situations is a static library, apps cannot embed it in the app bundle.

They also provide a way to fixed:

> you can solve this error by identifying the static framework and removing it from the Embedded Binaries section.

You accomplish this by following the instructions in [Inspecting A Binary's Linkage](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-USE_OTOOL)

Answer (score 5):

Adding below script into **Post-Actions** of **Archive** helped me overcome this issue. It removes static-frameworks which are unrelated.

```
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472
LOGFILE="${ARCHIVE_PATH}/static-frameworks.log"
echo "Removing static frameworks from ${WRAPPER_NAME} archive" > $LOGFILE
find "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/Applications/${WRAPPER_NAME}" -name '*.framework' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fm; do
    name=$(basename "${fm}" .framework)
    target="${fm}/${name}"
    echo "Checking: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    if file "${target}" | grep -q "current ar archive"; then
        rm -rf "${fm}"
        echo "Removed static framework: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    fi
done
```

A comment from Firebase issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472#issuecomment-771351512

Answer (score 5):

***2021! UPDATED***

Here is the hack for this:

1. Build the app with the `Pods_Runner.framework` marked as `Embed & Sign`

[image]

2. Once it's built. Go to the same place and set the `Pods_Runner.framework` to `Do Not Embed`.

[image]

3. Go to Product -> Archive -> Submit the archive and it will all work as expected.

credits: [lifenautjoe](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43499#issuecomment-571558841)

Answer (score 4):

Remove them from `Embedded Binaries` and add them to `Linked Frameworks and Libaries`, then Archive again and upload to store.

Comment: You should ensure you don't need the frameworks to be embedded (copied into the Frameworks folder) else you will get a dylib not found exception when you try to run on a device. This can be deceptive because it will work fine on the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

In my case in xcode 11, i resovle issue to set do not embeded in genral -> frameworks,libraies and embedded content [image]

Answer (score 3):

Check and looking for duplicate frameworks and Libraries in **Link Binary With Libraries** and **Embed Frameworks** in Build Phases tab of your project.

Only should be in one side ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is this the case? And which one (link or embed) should it be?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error with a FacebookSDK framework. I removed it from the Embed frameworks list in Build Phases and it solved the issue. Inspect the log and find the framework causing the error as mentioned by others.

Comment: I don't understand. The FacebookSDK's frameworks are dynamic, so shouldn't they be in "embed frameworks"?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue in a very simple Framework project. I only had one  target in my project for the framework and it was building fine. I wanted to add some unit tests, so I added two new targets: an iOS Unit Testing Bundle target, and a Single View Application target (to act as a host app for the tests). However, both new targets were throwing this error.

I discovered that the problem was caused by the Mach-O Type build setting on the new targets being set to Static Library. Apparently the new targets were inheriting the Mach-O type from the parent Project. When I set the Mach-O Type to the correct settings ("Bundle" for unit tests and "Executable" for the host app) it all worked! I also had to clean build, delete derived data and reset the simulator to get the new settings to take.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I selected the copy when installing and worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by change of Developer certificate/team.

I start project with personal Dev Apple ID and by the time I changed it to my work ID.
When we try to export .xcarchive then "Match-O header" fail did appear.
Nothing described here or at other sites don't change anything.

When I change Team back to my personal ID, error logs shows missing .xcent files for only few frameworks now (most recently added). So I start whole new project, paste all the sources and files, then run cocoapod and everything works as expect.

Answer (score 1):

My way of fixing this was to get back to `Fabric/Crashlytics` installation via Cocoapods instead of fancy Carthage setup (which appeared buggy).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a manually-added PFFacebookUtils framework in a Swift 2.3 non-CocoaPods project. I fixed it by removing said framework from the embedded frameworks section of the "General" page of the build target and linked it in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Given the amount of time I've poured into finding this problem, it was caused by Cocoapods. I was working on a Workspace that had both iOS apps and a command line tool to kick off some pipelines and stuff. My file looked like this:

```
target 'AppPipe' do
  platform :osx, '10.14'
  project 'AppPipe/AppPipe.xcodeproj'
  pod 'Yams'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['MACH_O_TYPE'] = 'staticlib'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I thought the `pods_install` hook was local to the scope I was writing it in, but it wasn't! It actually turned all of my target's configs into staticlibs! This fixed it:

```
target 'AppPipe' do
  platform :osx, '10.14'
  project 'AppPipe/AppPipe.xcodeproj'
  pod 'Yams'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # Only AppPipe always gets staticlib
        if target.name == 'AppPipe'
          config.build_settings['MACH_O_TYPE'] = 'staticlib'
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Xcode project for a static framework, your test target must have "Bundle" value for MACH_O_TYPE build setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When embedding bundles from library targets they may produce executables even with `Mach-O Type = Bundle`. So we can simply delete these executables from `xcarchive` (*Products/Applications/APP_NAME/YourBundle.bundle/YourBundle*)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as a script build-phase instead of a scheme post-build action. I found out of all the answers, this works the best:

```
# Fixes binary framework bug, see:
# https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_4-release-notes#Swift-Packages
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472

echo "Removing static frameworks from ${TARGET_NAME}.app"
find "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/" -name '*.framework' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fm; do
    name=$(basename "${fm}" .framework)
    target="${fm}/${name}"
    echo "Checking: ${fm}"
    if file "${target}" | grep -q "current ar archive"; then
        rm -rf "${fm}"
        echo "Removed static framework: ${fm}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem days ago, the root cause of this problem is:

** Some static libraries was wrongly embeded in the .app bundle. **

You can search .a or static .framework in the Products/*.app bundle in Xcode, and check out the project carefully, remove redundant static libraries.

Answer (score -1):

One of the possible reason is nested framework.

Inspired by Golang, I recently refactored my project's code from:

```
App(with all the code in one target)
```

to ("->" means link with, ABCD means framework)

```
B -> C
A -> B

App -> A
App -> B
App -> C
```

It turns out that nested framework is not officially supported by Apple. So I had to flatten the dependency tree to:

```
App -> D

D -> A
D -> B
D -> C
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue in Xcode 8 beta 3. I fixed it removing Fabric and Crashlytics from Linked frameworks (Project => Target => General page) ([source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50969))

Comment: That's not much of a "fix" if you actually need Fabric and Crashlytics (which I do).