# swift sodlib tool error happened when create a new target of Application Extension

Tags: swift, std, xcode8-beta3

my container App is written by objective-c,then I used Xcode8 beta3 to create a new target of Application Extension which used swift ,when I build my project ,I got the error:

`Effective srcDirs: {(
    <DVTFilePath:0x7fdca8e8fb40:'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator'>,
    <DVTFilePath:0x7fdcbdfc31f0:'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator'>
)}`

this error happened like in the progress of copying Swift standard libraries into xxx.app.

how can I fix this ,hope some one can help me

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you found a solution?

Comment: no , it seems like a bug of Xcode 8 beta3，you can try the Xcode8 beta4,maybe it fixed

Comment: I worked all right on Xcode8Beta4, so you can try ,if also have issue you can see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537684/error-while-attempting-to-run-my-app-using-xcode-8-beta-3