# Unexpected Mach-O header code when archiving an iOS Audiokit project

Tags: xcode, audiokit

I have an iOS AudioKit project that builds and runs in the simulator and physical device, but when I archive and then validate throws the error:

"Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"

In the critical log it states:

```
2018-07-11 20:05:58 +0000  Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
```

I've tried deleting derived data folder and reinstalling frameworks.

Running 
xCode 9.4.1
Audiokit 4.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is AudioKit related per se as we've been archiving AudioKit powered apps nearly daily for a while now. What's most likely happening is that you're treating AudioKit like a dynamic framework even though it is a static one.  That might survive local installs but then archive would complain.

Read more here:

[Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076819/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode-7)

Comment: Thanks Aurelius, the link led to the solution. I had a mismatch in how I embedded them and how I had them listed in the build settings. Probably from changing how I did it over the years.