# Issues in exporting ipa from xcarchive file using xcode in jenkins machine

Tags: xcode, jenkins, swift5, xcode10.2

I am finding an issue while exporting an IPA from an xcarchive file using xcode in jenkins machine. It was working before with xcode 10.1 with swift 4 but with updating xcode 10.2 with swift 5 its not working

Issues by running this command on teminal:

> xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath
>   '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/APPFolder/Build/APPName.xcarchive' -exportPath
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/APPFolder/Build
>   -exportOptionsPlist export_options_uat.plist

Receiving this error:

> IDEDistribution: Failed to generate distribution items with error:
>   Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O
>   header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=} error: exportArchive: Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

So, Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Siddharth

Comment: Check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076819/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode-7