# How to fix 'Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21' when submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, carthage, app-store-connect

I can't upload an archived version of my project to App Store Connect as I get the error 'Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21'.

I've already tried other suggestions, like checking the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase for any frameworks, but it's clean. I've also seen a Podfile extension that says it will fix it, but my dependency manager is Carthage, so I'm unable to use it.

```
2019-08-13 22:21:51 +0000  Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
```

Comment: Did you double check the "Embed Frameworks" in XCode as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218312/5329717 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had a static framework in my `input.xcfilelist` and `output.xcfilelist`. I just removed it and everything built fine!

Comment: In my case I was using xcodegen so I had to mark the framework not to embed  - carthage: AppCenter
        embed: false

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pods then just do two things.

Clean the project
Pods De-integrate -> pod install again This works for me.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i removed Fabric, Crashlytics, AppCenter frameworks from Carthage input.xcfilelist and output.xcfilelist because these frameworks are static.

Note: I found detailed information from log files "IDEDistribution.verbose.log".