# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am facing problems while submitting the react native ios app on App store. It works well. There is no problem in archiving also. But after archiving , When I try to distribute
the app I get an error "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21".
Xcode version: 11.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076819/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode-7)

Comment: Yes. But none of the solutions provided there worked for me

Comment: Did you solve it ? I a m having the same problem and I don't use cocoapods

Comment: yeah same here :-(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem although I think it was my own fault. I was upgrading an App for Admob 8 and the compatible Firebase version and I think while cleaning out the previous versions I deleted all the entries in General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content without realising that I also had GameKit and StoreKit frameworks in there. Whilst this carelessness had no effect on building and running for simulators and devices I got the Mach-O error when I tried to distribute the app to the store. Just dragging the frameworks back in fixed the problem for me.