# App wont compile for device because of watch kit - ValidateEmbeddedBinary Fails

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a pretty complex project and it includes phone, TV, and Watch apps.

Compiling for simulators is okay but compiling for a device (or archiving) causes ValidateEmbeddedBinary error:

> Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21
> Command ValidateEmbeddedBinary failed with a nonzero exit code

I cannot use the legacy build system because of the watch kit app, I tried cleaning, restarting, excluding some frameworks, pod install, re-login to the provisioning system but nothing worked.

What do you think?
Maybe it's because of device architecture? I'm not sure if I've seen arm64 before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076819/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode-7)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed the problem for the device; it's not about the watch app, it is about to watch app extension. I removed the watch ap extension.framework from the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section and it can be compiled now.

I m still getting exception after archived the project, in the Organizer App.