# XCode12.3 Archive Error "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, archive

I ready to upload my app to AppStore.
And I got an error `Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21`
What's wrong with my project.
Have any idea to fix it?

Here is IDEDistribution.critical.log :

```
Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
```

Here is IDEDistribution.standard.log :

```
2020-12-27 17:46:12 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: TDCCePassbook_TDCC_Staging, task: 2
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000 [MT] Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionAnalyzeArchiveStepViewController, context: <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf4878080; archive(resolved)='<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionTask(resolved)='2', distributionDestination(resolved)='1', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team(resolved)='(null)'>
    Chain (6, self inclusive):
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf4878080; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf4c743b0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf341a8c0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbd05632eb0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf34435b0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>', team='(null)'>
    <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf31d22a0; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fbcf349ef70>', distributionMethod='(null)', team='(null)'>
</IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fbcf4878080>
2020-12-27 17:48:58 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Here is IDEDistribution.verbose.log :

```
2020-12-27 17:46:12 +0000 [MT] Available distribution methods: {(
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fbd2a9c2d70>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAdHoc: 0x7fbd2a9c6540>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodDevelopmentSigned: 0x7fbd3f344d50>
)}
2020-12-27 17:46:12 +0000 [MT] Available distribution methods: {(
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fbd2a9c2d70>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAdHoc: 0x7fbd2a9c6540>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodiOSEnterprise: 0x7fbd2a9c7b20>,
    <IDEDistributionMethodDevelopmentSigned: 0x7fbd3f344d50>
)}
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000 [MT] Skipping reformat archive step by default.
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000 [MT] Skipping reformat archive step. No reformatter selected for archive <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34a14f0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf3450e20:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/SnapKit.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34e9430:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/TestAES.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf2ad1120:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf2ad1120:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf32b6c60:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34f85e0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/PushSDK.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf32b5790:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026c8c30:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026c8c30:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf2ad3530:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf2ad3530:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf4cc2ca0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf4cc2ca0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf344e270:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/RxSwift.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf31e1370:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf31e1370:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftsimd.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd08267040:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd08267040:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf344b690:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/RxRelay.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34de930:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/Kingfisher.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd083264b0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd083264b0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf46660b0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/TrueTime.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:14 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34432f0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd05c5ace0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd05c5ace0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd044cda20:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftAccelerate.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd044cda20:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftAccelerate.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf255b5a0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf255b5a0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd09149e30:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd09149e30:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd3ecca620:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd3ecca620:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd052b4510:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd052b4510:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026c3ac0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026c3ac0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf3448b10:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf32b6850:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf49c4c20:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf49c4c20:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026e2dd0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbd026e2dd0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf3440a00:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf3445e90:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf48b4060:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf48b4060:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib'>
2020-12-27 17:46:15 +0000  IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fbcf34f2ee0:'/Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-12-28/TestTarget 2020-12-28, 01.43.xcarchive/Products/Applications/TestTarget.app/Frameworks/TestBiometry.framework'>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076819/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode-7)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using CocoaPods plus a **framework** that gives you an error.

First of all, clean the derived data **( command + option + shift + k )** and `pod update` from terminal
If you still you get an error or already tried,

Go to General > Build Phases Tab in Xcode

- Try that **framework** remove from "Embedded binaries"

or

- Add that **framework** to your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"