# Xcode Mach-O error on project archive with OpenCV for IOS

Tags: c++, ios, flutter, opencv, testflight

in the project I'm currently working on, I integrated openCV to manipulate and evaluate images. The integration of OpenCV for IOS has worked well so far and everything works locally via my device when I build it via Xcode. However, if I want to archive the project to upload it to Testflight, I get this Mach-O error.

[image]

Here again to take it straight away what I have done to integrate. I hope it helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to search literally for this error? FYI: [Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33076819/7478597) or [Embedding Frameworks In An App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING)

Comment: @Scheff of course I did that first. And found that too. But until now I haven't been able to bring up a solution.