# Xcode - No such module after importing framework

Tags: swift3, module, frameworks, xcode9

I have imported a framework to using Xcode 9 Swift 3
The code works well as long as I build the project for simulator devices

[image]

However as soon as I select Gereric iOS Devices so I can Archive my project I get this error

[image]

Can someone please help on what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe your framework is not universal framework, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655698/how-to-archive-an-app-that-includes-a-custom-framework/35703033#35703033

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this framework in Binary.

Go to -> Target project -> Genral -> Embeded Binary.

Hope it works!

Comment: I have already done that , as I said it works fine in the simulator but when I want to Archive it through iOS Gereric Device it doesn't recognise the framework

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the (possibly Framework) top-level `modulemap` file, ensure that the module map file is named exactly `module.modulemap`.

(Whereas the top-level module map for export *should* be named something **other than** `module.modulemap`.)