# Can't upload iOS app to store with specific framework

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, frameworks, submission

The last week I've been dealing with properly adding frameworks into my iOS app so that I can upload it to the app store. I took out some dynamic frameworks, and replaced them with static ones. However, one of the frameworks I'm using is static (which I've double checked using the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591878/ios-is-it-a-static-or-a-dynamic-framework/32591983#32591983)), but the app store is still not allowing me to upload with it. I'm getting the following message when doing so:

> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/aaronmednick/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-06-20/myApp 6-20-18, 3.01 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/myapp.app/Python.framework/Versions/2.7" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}

For reference here's my output for checking that the Python.framework I'm using is a static one:

```
Aarons-MacBook-Air:Python.framework aaronmednick$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 aaronmednick  staff   24 Jun 19 20:58 Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
lrwxr-xr-x  1 aaronmednick  staff   23 Jun 19 20:58 Python -> Versions/Current/Python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 aaronmednick  staff   26 Jun 19 20:58 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 aaronmednick  staff  128 Jun 19 20:58 Versions
Aarons-MacBook-Air:Python.framework aaronmednick$ file Python 
Python: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures: [i386:current ar archive] [arm64]
Python (for architecture i386): current ar archive
Python (for architecture armv7):    current ar archive
Python (for architecture armv7s):   current ar archive
Python (for architecture x86_64):   current ar archive
Python (for architecture arm64):    current ar archive
```

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating the archive?  From within Xcode or from the command line with `xcodebuild`?

Comment: I'm doing it from within Xcode. Basically I set the device to "Generic iOS Device", and then I go to Product -> Archive.

Comment: Update: When I remove the Python.framework I can submit my app to the store, but my app doesn't work correctly.