# Xcode Unable to install app to iPhone(iOS 14.6): The code signature version is no longer supported

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I use flutter module in my iOS project. I can not run my project into an iPhone12(iOS 14.6), but iPhone XS(iOS 14.3) is ok.
The flutter module used in my project is in release mode.

Worried, because the deadline is coming up.
Help!
Thanks a lot!

env:

macOS Version 12.2.1 (Build 21D62)

Xcode 13.3.1 (20103) (Build 13E500a)

flutter 3.0

error info:

```
Details

Unable to install "ios_host"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-05-18 06:44:44 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001270079d1 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000127043ce7 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e254a76 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000127043a1d -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1422
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000120dfd668 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3414
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e386610 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010e3876f8 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 372
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ae0ad8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ae1cc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ae7cee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 696
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ae87c8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819af27e1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 758
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff819c95074 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff819c93ffb start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "14.6 (18F72)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 1251;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.2.1 (Build 21D62)
Xcode 13.3.1 (20103) (Build 13E500a)
Timestamp: 2022-05-18T14:44:44+08:00
```

Comment: I can run iOS project without `flutter module` into iPhone 12(iOS 14.6), but I can not run iOS project with `flutter module` into iPhone 12(iOS 14.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself:
embed flutter module(App.framework, Flutter.framework, etc) by CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Apple has changed the codesign signature to include DER encoded entitlements in addition to the plist encoded entitlements. This additional DER encoded entitlements section is required in iOS 15 and becomes the default behavior of codesign in the latest Xcode. To use codesign on an older machines with an older version of Xcode add the --generate-entitlement-der flag to your call to codesign.
```

If signing through Xcode, you can add this flag to the OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS setting in the Build Settings tab.this may be help:[The code signature version is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467306/the-code-signature-version-is-no-longer-supported)

Comment: Thanks. `Adding  --generate-entitlement-der flag` does not work, I tried. My Xcode's version is 13.3.1, it will sign code with flag `--generate-entitlement-der`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I accidentally embedded a framework that I should not embed.

From the [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup):

> Important: Plugins might produce static or dynamic frameworks. Static
> frameworks should be linked on, but never embedded. If you embed a
> static framework into your application, your application is not
> publishable to the App Store and fails with a Found an unexpected
> Mach-O header code archive error.

Check the answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591878/ios-is-it-a-static-or-a-dynamic-framework) to determine which frameworks are static.

Change static frameworks to ***"Do Not Embed"*** under your target’s ***General*** ->  ***Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content*** section.